# Wordpress CSS Menu Bug - Drop Down

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

I have a problem with my CSS at the moment. I am using wordpress and I am creating my own theme, when I came to create the navigation menu I am having a problem with making the menu Horizontal, with child pages and have it click-able. As it is I cannot hover on child pages.

http://www.ryansammut.info/mbf/

Has any one encountered the same problem, and how do you think it can be solved?

Update:

I had used a different CSS Menu to fix this.

Comment: a link to your website would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are floating a div and giving a width of 100% which is basically same as nothing happened except that you need to clear it. Set width to `width:auto;`.

Add `<div class="clear"></div>` where your floats should end.

and in css:

```
.clear {clear:both;height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;}
```

Also note that width:100% will still count + padding + margin + border to the total width.

This is what I would try from this code. Otherwise show us an example.

Comment: I am going to upload an online version of it, so you guys can get a better picture.